# Can I make a sequence skip certain values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sequence

In SQL server 2014 we are using sequences for some integer surrogate keys.

They begin in the negative values counting up.

Can we program the sequence to skip zero when the time comes?

The reason is because it's too easy for higher layer developers to accidentally initialize to the default value of the int and we'd like to protect against this in business logic (easy enough!)

But zero is actually a possible value in our sequence one day. It's not a problem to use any of the numbers, just easy to erroneously use zero.

We could write any number of validations and constraints to prevent this but I think the sequence itself would be the easiest.

Comment: There is no "skip a number or range" feature. What data type did you choose where you're going to need to worry about using up *half* the values but not all of them? In other words, if you're worried about what happens when you get to zero, shouldn't you be more worried about what happens when you hit the other end and exhaust all of the values?

Comment: Perhaps add a constraint - `CHECK (table_id <> 0)`? The sequence won't skip 0 but the insert will fail.

Comment: Starting at negative side let's us use the full range of the data type. I'm not concerned about using half. I'm concerned specifically about zero. Both -1 and 1 are fine.... Even zero is fine... But it's easy to accidentally use zero

Comment: I understand what starting at the negative side does. My point is the same... if you're going to use half the range aren't you going to use the whole range? e.g. if you are using `int` you're going to use at least 2 billion values, if you're going to use at least 2 billion values for 0 to be a concern, aren't you going to use at least 4 billion values? What is your plan then? On the other hand, if you use `bigint` instead, you could just start at 1, and *never* use 0 and *never* exhaust the values supported by the data type. Compression makes those 8 bytes a lot smaller until you hit 2 billion

Comment: If you can't or won't change your strategy then I agree with @ypercubeᵀᴹ - add a check constraint and make sure your insert has try/catch logic. That one time the constraint fails, you can catch the error, re-try (now the sequence will generate 1), and even dynamically drop the constraint at that point. Another option is to have a trigger that, when it gets close to 0, automatically adjusts the sequence and even drops itself. Or sends you an e-mail to ask you to do it manually.

Comment: One option would be to use `increment by 2` and start with an odd number. Only half of the possible numbers available but you will not have a zero. `create sequence dbo.AtOdds as bigint start with -9223372036854775807 increment by 2;`

Comment: I don't think it's likely I will exhaust the values for int, but this strategy is also used sometimes with smallints too. I'm more just thinking if there's a recommendation for remediating this failure mode.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson interesting idea but that rather defeats the choice of starting from negative / trying to use the full breadth.